# Simple WPF UI layout creation

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface

I would like to create a layout, three regions Header, maincontent and footer. The header will have a ribbon hence when the ribbon is minimized the main content will strech.  The footer will have a expander hence when the expander is collapsed (downward) the main content will stretch. I am looking for xaml which will do this. Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: `DockPanel` looks like a good candidate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DockPanel will do nicely - or you can use a Grid:

```
   <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Menu Grid.Row="0">Ribbon Content Here</Menu>
        <Panel Grid.Row="1">Main content here</Panel>
        <Panel Grid.Row="2">Footer Content Here</Panel>
    </Grid>
```

[Link to MS Ribbon Control Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11877) - use if it fits